# Feature test for authenticated user with auth middleware missing

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class that sets `auth` middleware in controller, like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
    }

    public function something()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

And a test like this:

```
class MyControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->actingAs($user);
        $this->get('api/something');
    }
}
```

The expected output is a dump of the user.
Everything works as expected, both in real application and in feature test.

**The problem begins here:** If I remove this line: `$this->middleware('auth:api');` the output is the dump of user in tests but in real application it gets `null`. This is a problem as I can't rely on feature test.

With `actingAs()` Laravel seems to authenticate the user under the hood and then the test pass but the application fails. Is this a bug or there is something I'm missing here?

Using Laravel 7.x

Answer (score -1):

If I understand right - you want test "is route has middleware". Than add to your tests:

```
public function testAuth()
{
  //without acting as
  $this->get('api/something')->assertForbidden();
}
```

With this, you can be you can be sure that `Auth::user()` is not null.

Comment: No, the problem is if, for some reason,I forget to write `$this->middleware('auth:api');` the test pass but the real application fails, as it doesn't have an authenticated user, while the test have.

Comment: Than, my solution is working - dedicated test to check auth middleware

Comment: No it isn't. The test behave different than application.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte But why? If you forget about auth - this test fail. If not - no matter how laravel auth users - you sure you have user in real app.